# Clone/Unclone in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to 'clone' an image (showing it twice on the same page) as well as to hide it again on button clicks.

Is there a way to get it work using the function below?

```js
$(".clone-button").on("click", function() {})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cloneControls" class="card">
    <h4 class="card-header">Double Power!</h4>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg clone-button">
                <span class="fa fa-ok"></span>
                Clone
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg unclone-button">
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                Unclone
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have just started learning Javascript and JQuery. I already did some research, tried toggle, bootstrap clone, even created getElementID, however, none of my approaches seemed to work. Apparently I am understanding it wrong, can anybody give me some first advice please?

Comment: Can you include the relevant `javascript` / `jQuery` to your question please? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/uostg2xy/) might be of some help but you will no doubt have to make changes to fit your needs.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve]. This site is not meant to be a micro job portal 'please do this little task for me.' You should expose at least one of your own approaches first and people will be happy to help you to improve your coding skills.

Comment: Clone what and put it where? No image shown in this markup. Also show what you have tried. Question is incomplete

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy using JQuery's `clone` method. Note that it produces duplicate IDs. You have to remove them yourself. `clone` does not copy within the DOM. You have to insert the new node subsequently.

Since almost every JQuery method returns the JQuery collection, you can chain method invokations without using variables.

```js
$(".clone-button").on("click", function() 
{
  $('#to-clone')
    .clone()
    .addClass('cloned')
    .attr('id',null)           // we do not want duplicate IDs
    .insertAfter('#to-clone');
});

$(".unclone-button").on("click", function() 
{
  $('.cloned').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cloneControls" class="card">
    <h4 class="card-header">Double Power!</h4>
    <img id="to-clone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg clone-button">
                <span class="fa fa-ok"></span>
                Clone
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg unclone-button">
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                Unclone
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, and thank you very much for pointing out that it produces duplicate ID, so helpful :)